# Bash script MV is disappearing files

Tags: bash

I've written a script to go through all the files in the directory the script is located in, identify if a file name contains a certain string and then modify the filename.  When I run this script, the files that are supposed to be modified are disappearing.  It appears my usage of the mv command is incorrect and the files are likely going to an unknown directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

string_contains="dummy_axial_y_position"
string_dontwant="dummy_axial_y_position_time"
file_extension=".csv"

for FILE in *
do
    if [[ "$FILE" == *"$string_contains"* ]];then
            if [[ "$FILE" != *"$string_dontwant"* ]];then
                 filename= echo $FILE | head -c 15
                 combined_name="$filename$file_extension"
                 echo $combined_name
                 mv $FILE $combined_name
                 echo $FILE
                 
            fi
    fi
done
```

I've done my best to go through the possible errors I've made in the MV command but I haven't had any success so far.

Comment: Why are you using `if` instead of `for FILE in *"$string_contains"*"$file_extension"`?

Comment: Your syntax for setting the `filename` variable is not correct. See [how do I set a variable to the output of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)

Comment: You can also use `${FILE:0:15}` to get the first 15 characters of the variable, no need for external commands.

Comment: You should check your script with shellcheck.net before posting here.

Comment: yeah, that looks like it would set it to nothing, meaning the combined name would be '.csv' which would appear as a hidden file.

Comment: As the bash tag you used already told you - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems and several places where your script can be improved.

---

```bash
filename= echo $FILE | head -c 15
```

This pipeline [runs `echo $FILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) adding the variable `filename` having the null string as value in its environment. This value of the variable is visible only to the `echo` command, the variable is not set in the current shell. `echo` does not care about it anyway.

You probably want to capture the output of `echo $FILE | head -c 15` into the variable `filename` but this is not the way to do it.
You need to use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) for this purpose:

```bash
filename=$(echo $FILE | head -c 15)
```

`head -c` outputs only the first 15 characters of the input file (they can be on multiple lines but this does not happen here). `head` is not the most appropriate way for this. Use `cut -c-15` instead.
But for what you need (extract the first 15 characters of the value stored in the variable `$FILE`), there is a much simpler way; use a form of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) called "substring expansion":

```bash
filename=${FILE:0:15}
```

---

```bash
mv $FILE $combined_name
```

Before [running `mv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion), the variables `$FILE` and `$combined_name` are expanded (it is called ["parameter expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)). This means that the variable are replaced by their values.

For example, if the value of `FILE` is `abc def` and the value of `combined_name` is `mnp opq`, the line above becomes:

```bash
mv abc def mnp opq
```

The `mv` command receives 4 arguments and it attempts to move the files denoted by the first three arguments into the directory denoted by the fourth argument (and it probably fails).

In order to keep the values of the variables as single words (if they contain spaces), always [enclose them in double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-quoting). The correct command is:

```bash
mv "$FILE" "$combined_name"
```

This way, in the example above, the command becomes:

```bash
mv "abc def" "mnp opq"
```

... and `mv` is invoked with two arguments: `abc def` and `mnp opq`.

---

```bash
combined_name="$filename$file_extension"
```

There isn't any problem in this line. The quotes are simply not needed.
The variables `filename` and `file_extension` are expanded (replaced by their values) but on [assignments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) word splitting is not applied. The value resulted after the replacement is the value assigned to variable `combined_name`, even if it contains spaces or other word separator characters (spaces, tabs, newlines).

---

The quotes are also not needed here because the values do not contain spaces or other characters that are special in the command line. They must be quoted if they contain such characters.

```bash
string_contains="dummy_axial_y_position"
string_dontwant="dummy_axial_y_position_time"
file_extension=".csv"
```

It is not not incorrect to quote the values though.

---

```bash
for FILE in *
do
    if [[ "$FILE" == *"$string_contains"* ]];then
        if [[ "$FILE" != *"$string_dontwant"* ]]; then
```

This is also not wrong but it is inefficient.
You can use the expression from the `if` condition directly in the `for` statement (and get rid of the `if` statement):

```bash
for FILE in *"$string_contains"*; do
    if [[ "$FILE" != *"$string_dontwant"* ]]; then
    ...
```

---

If you have read and understood the above (and some of the linked documentation) you will be able to figure out yourself where were your files moved :-)

Comment: Thank you!  This was extremely helpful.  Read through the linked documentation and have a much better understanding of how these commands operate now.